# How to write a singleton class in javascript using IIFE module pattern?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, module, iife

How to write a singleton class in javascript using IIFE module pattern ?
Can you plz provide an example?

I tried something like this, but it fails for x2.getInstance.
As per my understanding, x2.getInstance() should get the same instance as x1.getInstance(). How can I achieve this using IIFE module pattern ??

```
var x = (function(){

    var instance ;
    var vconstructor = function(){};
    //vconstructor.prototype.method1 = function(){}
    //vconstructor.prototype.method2 = function(){}
    vconstructor.prototype.getInstance = function(){
        if (!instance) {
          console.log('critical section');
          instance = somefunc();
          return instance;
    }
    };  

    function somefunc(){
        return { "key1": "value1"};
    }

    return vconstructor;
})();

var x1 = new x();
console.log('1.');
console.log(x1 instanceof x);
console.log(x1);
console.log('2.' + x1.getInstance());  
var x2 = new x();
console.log(x2);
console.log('x2: ' + x2.getInstance());
```

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var Singleton = (function () {
    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new Object("I am the instance");
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

function run() {

    var instance1 = Singleton.getInstance();
    var instance2 = Singleton.getInstance();

    alert("Same instance? " + (instance1 === instance2));  
}
```

Comment: well, i wanted to use the new() keyword with IIFE and it just wasnt working.

Comment: I had tried this, but here we are just calling module.api(), which works but i wanted to do it with new(); the problem is with new, the return statement has to be the constructor function. if we do something like this return { getInstance: function(){} }, it freaking breaks

Comment: anyways I was finally able to get it working, here https://plnkr.co/edit/A83pzHKJcsGW2DlFWUGO?p=preview

Comment: I am open to any more solutions ... or if there is a better way to do it which betters my solution. wasted 2 days on this.